# get directly a value from Firebase on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have manually added some date on my firebase server. It has a key and a value. Is it possible to get the value of the key without using onDataChange? I just want to get the value that is there without any connditions if the data is changed or something.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method of Firebase object. It does use onDataChange but it is invoked only once so you just get the current value.

Comment: thank you, I am going to explore it for a while and tell you my opinion for it

Comment: using onDataChange is obviously neccesary since you need the callback for asynchronous network request, even when you get the value just once.

Comment: I want to get the highscore from the users and compare if theirs is higher. So in this case Firebase isn't the best solution it seems >.<

Comment: What do you mean? it gets the value just when you add the listener - it doesn't wait till the data on server changes.

Comment: interface callback name is obviously unfortunate - onDataChange just means that it changes for you "locally". When you first add the listener the value for that reference link is null locally, then it gets the value that is on the server instantly and invokes "onDataChange".

Comment: I really appreciate your effords. Thank you for clarifying me and further people that may read this. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Android documentation has a [section](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once) about this.

The code would look like this:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    // do some stuff once
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
}
```

});

Comment: yes but... i need to take the value that is there before it is every changed ;s

Comment: Your answer is correct aswell, I was just confused because I am such a newbie. My apologizes